# Preset jest-puppeteer is invalid

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

in a working jest + puppeteer project,
i'm moving to jest-circus in order to use the [jest-circus retry feature](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestretrytimes).
As documented, i installed jest-circus and i set as runner but running test as usual i obtain

```
 Validation Error:

  Preset jest-puppeteer is invalid:

  The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object
  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:3)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at setupPreset (C:\src\qa-e2e-update-stack\node_modules\jest-config\build\normalize.js:348:14)
    at normalize (C:\src\qa-e2e-update-stack\node_modules\jest-config\build\normalize.js:703:15)
    at readConfig (C:\src\qa-e2e-update-stack\node_modules\jest-config\build\index.js:220:68)
    at async readConfigs (C:\src\qa-e2e-update-stack\node_modules\jest-config\build\index.js:401:26)
    at async runCLI (C:\src\qa-e2e-update-stack\node_modules\@jest\core\build\cli\index.js:203:59)
    at async Object.run (C:\src\qa-e2e-update-stack\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js:216:37)

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

this is my jest.config.js file

```
const fs = require('fs')
reportFolder = "reports"
if (!fs.existsSync(reportFolder)){
    fs.mkdirSync(reportFolder)
}

module.exports = {
    preset: "jest-puppeteer",
    testRunner: "jest-circus/runner",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [  // NOT setupFiles
        "./configurazioni/custom-configuration.js",
        "./configurazioni/shared-require.js",
        "jest-allure/dist/setup"
    ],
    "reporters": [
        "default",
        ["./node_modules/jest-html-reporter", {
            "pageTitle": "Test Report",
            "includeFailureMsg": true,
            "includeConsoleLog": true,
            "outputPath":"reports/"+new Date().getDate() + "-" +
                (new Date().getMonth() + 1) + "-"
                + new Date().getFullYear()+ "-"
                + new Date().getHours().toString() + "-"
                + (new Date().getMinutes() + 1 ).toString() + "-"
                + (new Date().getSeconds() + 1 ).toString()
                +"-run.html"
        }],
        ["jest-junit", { outputName: "reports/junitreport.xml" }]
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: { 
        '^\\$lib\/(.*)': `<rootDir>/lib/$1`,
    },
};
```

i don't found any page talking about my issue, jest-circus and jest-preset cannot coexists?

Comment: I'm seeing this error without jest-circus so it looks like something's broken

Answer (score 1):

I've got such error when `rootDir` was set incorrectly in jest config file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check whether your node packages are properly installed. I encountered the very same issue when my node_modules folder got deleted.